# Abort external process if it takes too long to complete

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch script which processes many files at once using an external Python script. I'd like to implement a feature where, if the Python script hangs on any file for too long (e.g. the file is corrupted), the Python script will terminate and the batch script will move onto the next file. I have seen others on this site suggest using a timeout for terminating a program after a certain amount of time; however, that is far from ideal for this scenario, as that will add that many seconds to the running time of the script for each tile.

My question is: is there a way to limit the running time of an external process, without causing a delay if the process completes before the time is up?

Here is a bit of my code. TexIDfix.py at the end is the Python script which I need to prevent from hanging. Any help is much appreciated :)

```
:fixer
for /f %%f in ('dir /b "workspace\content\patch\data\fighter\%1\model\%3"') do (
    set val=%%f
    set val=!val:~1!
    if /I !val!==01 set val=1
    if /I !val!==02 set val=2
    if /I !val!==03 set val=3
    if /I !val!==04 set val=4
    if /I !val!==05 set val=5
    if /I !val!==06 set val=6
    if /I !val!==07 set val=7
    if /I !val!==08 set val=8
    if /I !val!==09 set val=9
    set /a "val=val*4"
    if /I !val! GTR 255 (
        set /a "mod/=255"
        echo !mod!
        set /a "val=val-(255*mod)"
        echo !val!
    )
    TexIDfix.py "workspace\content\patch\data\fighter\%1\model\%3\%%f\%2.nud" "workspace\content\patch\data\fighter\%1\model\%3\%%f\model.nut" !val!
)

goto:eof
```

Comment: What do you want your code to do exactly, and what does it actually do?

Comment: The batch script starts a Python script, giving it two files and a number as input (the number depends on the folder that the two files are in). The Python script changes the data inside of the files based on the folder, without getting into too much detail.

The script currently works fine in that regard (this is only one of the functions). However, if the Python script encounters a certain type of file, it stops and hangs on that one file indefinitely, and the batch file never finishes. Thus, what I need is a way to end the TexIDfix.py process prematurely if it stays running for too long.

Comment: See the waitfor command. Use in two batches.